# How can I find the largest subset among these subsets by creating subsets of non-contiguous integer elements in a integer set with c#?

Tags: c#

How can I find the largest subset among these subsets by creating subsets of non-contiguous integer elements in a integer set?

Example made with python

https://gelecegiyazanlar.turkcell.com.tr/soru/alt-kume-hesaplama

Comment: So what have you tried so far and what is the problem with the `c#` code you've written? If you're looking for someone to write the code for you I'm afraid you've stumbled upon the wrong websites, plenty of sites out there where you can hire people to do coding work for you

Comment: This is a trick question.  The answer is very simple.  It is always the even indexes of the array.  So [-2,1,3,-4,5] it is indexes 0, 2, 4 [-2,3,5].

Comment: Right! I never thought like that. Thank You very much!